# Itunes connect Rejection- iPhone only

Tags: xcode, swift, app-store-connect

I submitted my game to the app store and it got rejected because it didn't comply to iPad sizing, were I specified on iPhone on Xcode.
[image]

Yet apple thought otherwise.

[image]

Am I missing something? Where else do I specify only iPhone? iTunes Connect?

Comment: Apps built only for iPhones can also be run on an iPad in lower resolution. Try installing Instagram or any other iPhone only app and notice the '1x','2x' button on the bottom right corner.

Comment: You'd have to ensure that that your 'iPhone only' app is able to run on an iPad in the low resolution mode. Create an ad-hoc build of the app and test it on an iPad. See if you can reproduce the problem which the reviewers reported.

Answer (score 1):

Check that you have

```
Scene.scaleMode = .aspectFit
```

added in the `ViewController.swift` file.

I had it set to `aspectFill` and it messed up the iPad view. When I changed it to `.aspectFit`, it worked great.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to adjust that is is a iPhone only app not a ipodtouch/iPhone. Then you should pass.

In the application's `Build Settings` change the `Targeted Device Family` to iPhone, instead of iPhone/iPad or to 1 instead of 1,2.

I added a screenshot but my app is universal so i have both 1,2 set.

[image: info.plist]

Comment: I do have it as only 1

Comment: well the other option is just add the necessary things for ipad.